# How to solve for the possible values of a diagonal?

Tags: geometry

Problem: A quadrilateral plot of land is given to a farmer. The area of the plot is $32$. Also, the sum of length of two opposite sides of the plot and one of its diagonal is $16$. Seeds have to be sown along the other diagonal of the plot. If the cost of sowing seeds along 1 unit length is $\sqrt{3}$, find the sum of all possible costs the farmer may have to pay for this.

Approach: taking a random quadrilateral i used the fact that $a+c+d_1(\text{diagonal}) = 16$ and $1/2ad_1\sin\theta_1 +1/2cd_1\sin\theta_2 =32$, but didn't progress ahead, so tried inequality on the $d_2$ value using the triangle inequality of $d_1+d_2 >a+c$ or $d_1+d_2>b+d$ but that also doesn't work. Any strategy?

Comment: use mathjax for eqns

Comment: Sure from next time i will try

Comment: Sum of all possible costs? If there are no other restrictions, this is infinity

Comment: Area restriction and sum constraint might turn out to be useful?

Comment: I hate when a contractor charges me $8\sqrt{6}$ dollars.

Comment: What ? You are able to find the possible values @aschepler?

Comment: I believe there's only one possible value, and the constraints force $\sin \theta_1 = \sin \theta_2 = 1$.

Comment: Proof @aschepler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the case where the plot is a parallelogram.

Take parallelogram $ABCD$, let $AD=BC=x$, $AC=y$, $BD=z$, $\angle ACB =\theta$.

$$2x+y=16 \Rightarrow y=16-2x$$
$$xy \sin\theta = 32 \Rightarrow 16x-2x^2=\frac{32}{\sin\theta}$$

Here we see that there are infinitely many $\theta$'s that can satisfy the conditions.

$$(\frac{z}{2})^2 = x^2+(\frac{y}{2})^2-2x(\frac{y}{2})\cos\theta = 64-\frac{32+32\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$$
This would also have infinitely many possible values.

Therefore, the answer is infinity.

Comment: The answer given by @aschepler is given to be correct in the options

Comment: Have you really put all the information given in the problem into your post?

Comment: This was given in the problem only nothing else .

Comment: Why have you taken AD =BC by the way @jim?

Comment: Because $ABCD$ is a parallelogram. I only took the case where the plot is a parallelogram and there were infinitely many possibilities, which is sufficient to show that there are infinitely many possibilities when considering all quadrilaterals.